# imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file

Tags: java, image

I've started Java a week ago, and now I would like to insert an image into my window.
Whatever I try I keep having this in Eclipse:
**javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!**

```
package graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import src.Common;

public class Window extends JFrame
{
public class Panel extends JPanel
{

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Image img; 
        try 
        {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("/logo.jpg"));
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public Window(String title, int width, int height)
{
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setSize(width, height);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setContentPane(new Panel()); 
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

I think the code is pretty self-explaining.
I tried to solve the problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841741/java-unknown-source-with-imageio?rq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130982/imageio-cant-read-input-file?rq=1), and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713096/javax-imageio-iioexception-for-apparently-no-reason) .

What I'm trying to do is a desktop program, and my sources are stored like that :
training/src/graphics/Window
training/src/src/main

I did put the image I want to read in every folder, and still getting the issue :/

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT Finally solved, here the answer**

nIcE cOw gave me the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) that helped.
So I did put my images into a folder, and change the way to access to them, as described in the link.

```
getClass().getResource("/images/yourImageName.extension");
```

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230). I hope it helps :-) To know how to access images, you can see the last link in that answer :-)

Comment: You can find more info regarding the same at the [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) page of [tag:embedded-resource] tag :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried using `new File("logo.jpg");` (without the leading /)?

And are you sure, the logo.jpg is copied to your output? (Some IDEs don't copy every file from your source-directories to your output (or target) directories.)

```
/src
|-> Window.java
|-> Logo.jpg
```

becomes

```
/out
|-> Window.class
```

(Note that the IDE/compiler does not copy the image to your output-directory and so the compiled code cannot find the image - allthough you did specify the correct path)

Comment: Yup, i did try that though (should had mentionned it).

I copied "Logo.jpg" Through the Windows user interface, not through eclipse.
SO you mean, i should copy the images onto the output files from the IDE? how ? :/

Comment: I think, eclipse copies the files automatically. Does your file has to be inside your project? If it is inside your project, you should try to load it with the classloader. (`this.getClass().getResource("images/beam.png")`)

Answer (score 6):

Try do **debug which file resource you actually try to access**. First step would be to get your `new File("/logo.jpg").get [Canonical]Path()` and print it to `System.out` (or alternatively watch in the the debugger). I guess the problem is the `/` before `logo.jpg`, which points to your root directory (e.g. c:) and your file isn't there, but I don't know your file setup in detail.

Comment: When i try to print, it doesn't print anything :(
I also tryed without the "/" before "Logo.jpg", but it doesn't change anything.
My setup is : C:\Documents and Settings\USER\workspace\training\src\graphics

Comment: `new File(...).getPath()` will print something for sure. You can also try `new File()`, or `new File("")` if you are unsure. In case you don't see any output, try printing a random string as prefix (e.g. "my directory is ") to test your console.

Comment: Finally, i've got the solution, i edited my first post, but i can't close the thread :o
But thanks for the help !

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're looking at nothing before the image, so it's looking into a folder that isn't there to find it.

You have to create a folder to store the images in your project, and then call to it, your folder name in front of the image name. e.g.

```
ImageIO.read(new File("Folder/Image.png"));
```

Otherwise you can find the image by going through the entire directory, which isn't a good way as it takes longer, and when you move your project it won't be a working link as the directory will be different. For example:

```
ImageIO.read(new File("D:/eclipse/Workspace/Project/Folder/Image.png"));
```

Creating a folder in your project so its on the same level as the source folder in the directory and call to it for the image, like so:

> Folder structure;
>
> settings
>
> src
>
> Image Folder
>
> bin

Answer (score 1):

copypasting from a working project:

```
  private JPanel getPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel labelLcl = new JLabel("Ye ana!");
    try {
        File f = new File("./src/res/0.jpg");
        //l.a(f.getCanonicalPath());
        BufferedImage imgLcl = ImageIO.read(f);
        ImageIcon iconLcl = new ImageIcon(imgLcl);
        labelLcl.setIcon(iconLcl );
        panel.add(labelLcl);
  } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
    return panel;
}
```

otherwise you can have folder/file read permission problem